# How can I automatically attach a comment to a post?

Tags: python, django

I have a form for creating comments that already knows how to determine which user the message is from, but it does not know how to join the post to which it is written.

Here are models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=8000)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/', null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    connect_category = models.ManyToManyField('Category')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        if self.image:
            img = Image.open(self.image.path)

            if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
                new_img = (500, 600)
                img.thumbnail(new_img)
                img.save(self.image.path)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', args=[str(self.id)])


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)



class Comments(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    approved = 'Approved'
    refused = 'Refused'
    choice = (
        (approved, 'Одобрено'),
        (refused, 'Отказано')
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=choice, default='Ожидание')
    connect_post = models.ForeignKey('Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post', args=[str(self.id)])
```

views.py:

```
class PostDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post.html'
    context_object_name = 'post'
    form_class = CommentForm
    success_url = ''

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['comment_form'] = CommentForm(initial={'connect_post': self.object.id})
        return context


class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = CommentForm
    success_url = '/'
    model = Comments

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        post_id = form.cleaned_data['connect_post']
        form.instance.connect_post = post_id
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    connect_post = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = {
            'text',
        }
        exclude = ['author', 'connect_post']
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='news'),
    path('post/<int:pk>', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post'),
    path('create/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('<int:pk>/edit/', PostEdit.as_view(), name='post_edit'),
    path('profile/', Profile, name='profile'),
    path('addcom', CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='comment_create'),
    path('usercomments/', user_comments, name="usercomments"),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I tried to access the user ID using the Postdetails method of the form_valid class, and then pass it to the creator view and only then to the CommentForm form. But it didn't work and it gave me this error: "ValueError in /addcom can't assign "1": "Comments.connect_post" must be an instance of "Post"."

As I understand it, he does not want to search by post id and requires something else. How can I implement joining a post automatically?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error already indicates, `connect_post` should be an instance of `Post`. But since you only pass in an integer, it will not gonna work.

You have two options to solve it:

1. use that id as integer then you need to change `form.instance.connect_post = post_id` to `form.instance.connect_post_id = post_id`
2. pass in an instance of `Post`: use some kind of logic to get the post object by the id. E.g.

```
post = get_object_or_404()
post_id = form.cleaned_data['connect_post']
post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
form.instance.connect_post = post
```